# NAB benchmark (Numenta Anomaly Benchmark)

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data

I have doubt on how to use NAB dataset for real time anomaly detection. The available datasets, for example the New York City taxi dataset, contains only 2 columns of timestamp and value, but where are the labels to predict the AUC for the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

The anomallies sometimes are not marked as anomallies, the task consists in checking by yourself which are anomallies, but you have nothing to compare to.